# Dark theme android app

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I'm trying to create a dark theme similar to the one in OxygenOS on OnePlus devices.

[image]

I changed the window background to black but the problem is the action bar is not becoming pure black.

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompact">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Replace these values in your colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#101010</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
```

This would be enough to change the Toolbar's color.

---

If you don't want to change the whole app primary color (which seems it is what you were trying to do in the first place), try creating a new Toolbar by:

**Add this to your app's build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

**Add this to your main layout (activity_main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="mx.evin.apps.startingtemplate.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/a_main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Set this in your styles (styles.xml):**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**And set the new toolbar (MainActivity.java).**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.a_main_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 16):

**SIMPLEST SOLUTION**

You can enable/disable dark theme just by:

1. enable dark theme:

   ```
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
   ```
2. forcefully disable dark theme:

   ```
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
   ```
3. set app theme based on mobile settings of dark mode, i.e. if dark mode is enabled then the theme will be set to a dark theme, if not then
   the default theme, but this will only work in **version >= Android version Q**

   ```
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
   ```

**Notes:**

1. Your base theme for app/activity should be

> "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

like

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2. Your res folder's names would end with -night so that different colors and images you can set for day and night themes like

drawable & drawable-night,
values & values-night

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a dark theme (or black theme) is very easy today thanks to

> Theme.DayNight and 
>   AppCompatDelegate

Android comes to us allowing us to declare

> night/colors.xml

and

> night/styles.xml

Full example here: https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/DarkTheme

Answer (score 2):

With the Material Components we can use two values folder i.e. values (for light theme) & values-night (for dark theme) or can also manage the `dayNight` theme with the styling using:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

For a Dark Action Bar a theme parent should be:

```
 parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
```

To set Dark theme we can use this method of AppCompatDelegate

```
setDefaultNightMode(
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

[More](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94)  details on how this works with different API levels.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support Dark Theme first thing you will need to do is to make sure your theme inherits from DayNight theme.

After you’re done, the theme should look like the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

Essentially the DayNight theme works with two directories - Light theme inside values directory and Dark inside values-night directory.

Therefore whenever you want to use different resource values, depending on the theme, you need to declare that resource in both above directories.

For instance you could create two different color resources like this:

`values/colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#f2f2f2</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#29b6f6</color>
```

`values-night/colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#2e2f32</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#121212</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#90caf9</color>
```

That should be it, you can read about it in more detail on my blog

https://androidexplained.github.io/ui/android/material-design/2020/09/24/dark-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

No one mention about this as the other answer implying that Dark = Night. No! `Dark Mode` is not `Night Mode`. They are completely different. DM was introduce in Android 10 that enforce built-in black and white color thus it can be change via device settings while NM exist already on earlier version that uses either default/defined style depending on your implementation and usually can be change inside the app settings. If you want your app to use your define light/night style and not relying on built-in dark style, you may want to `forceDarkAllowed` to false in themes.xml or style.xml as DM may conflict.