# DIfference between MODE_NIGHT_YES and MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM on dark mode enabled

Tags: android, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I have a settings activity with this attribute on manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" >
```

and i have

```
    android:forceDarkAllowed="true"
    android:configChanges="uiMode"
```

but when i set dark mode on the phone and on the app i use setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM); everything it's ok, instead when I set dark mode disabled on the phone and I set AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES something do wrong.

I do an example (pixel 3a with Android 10)
Dark mode on phone disabled and             AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES); on app
[image]

Dark mode on phone enabled and AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
[image]

So... What is wrong? Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60414493/8874958 this might help you !

Comment: So...How can I tell the color of the text and the background color in settings?

Comment: set textview's text color from colors.xml file which resides in values folder. For night theme, you have to create one new folder "values-night" in same hierarchy, which contains colors.xml file in it and the color value should be based on the night theme. So you will have 2 values folders with different colors in it based on theme. Colors name in both the files should be same but values may different.

Comment: https://github.com/kishansolanki124/Android-Night-Mode this may help you @Andrea Giga Ravalli

Comment: @KishanSolanki something work.. but it's inverted! When i choose day the bar become on day color but the background it's dark..I'll be crazy.