# Statusbar font color not change with fragment Darktheme in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, statusbar

I Set Two themes in my app AppTheme & DarkTheme

In my Apptheme status bar is show proper but when I set DarkTheme its change statusbar color but font color is not changed, **I want to change my status bar font color white in DarkTheme.**

When I use fragment in activity , like MainFragment use in MainActivity that time my statusbar color not being white

When I use Only Activity its give proper result in same theme with white font color in statusbar.

**Style.xml**

```
  <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryD</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_82828C</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_f85200</item>
        <item name="color_background">@color/color_background_night_light_black</item>
        <item name="color_background_d">@color/color_background_night_dark_black</item>
        <item name="color_icon">@color/color_icon_ffffff</item>
        <item name="color_black_white">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="color_catlist_bg">@color/color_background_night_dark_black</item>
        <item name="color_icon_border">@color/color_icon_border_night</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_colorD</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="color_background">@color/color_background_day</item>
        <item name="color_background_d">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_f85200</item>
        <item name="color_icon">@color/color_icon_3b3b3b</item>
        <item name="color_black_white">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="color_catlist_bg">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="color_icon_border">@color/color_icon_border_day</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
```

**1)** Apptheme statusbar is proper

[image]

**2)** DarkTheme Statusbar font color is black I want to white color font

[image]

I Alredy Applied many solution but not work in my case

**HomeActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

**The issue with Activity with fragment, without fragment status bar font color white work.**

if anyone has any solution then give me a suggestion, if in my case its work I also right mark on the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If You change status bar font color white use this funtion,

For Java,

```
public static void setLightStatusBar(Activity activity){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int flags = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        }
    }
```

For kotlin use this Extension function,

```
fun Activity.setLightStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        var flags = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility
        flags =
            flags and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
    }
}
```

**If you want to clear light status bar and restore to previous state then use this function,**

For Java,

```
 public static void clearLightStatusBar(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat
                    .getColor(activity, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    }
```

For Kotlin,

```
fun Activity.clearLightStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat
            .getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    }
}
```

Comment: remove setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme); if you applied

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957735/dark-theme-android-app/60422653#60422653) out for implementing the perfect combo light/dark theme. There is a full example by Google itself.

I don't know why you switch between themes, DarkTheme style isn't more required today since we can use `night/colors.xml` and `night/styles.xml`. In both of them you can override your resources of light theme. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

***Note : Status bar coloring is not supported below API level 21.***

**For API 21 and above 21**

You can change it by setting the android:statusBarColor or android:colorPrimaryDark attribute of the style you're using for your app in styles.xml.

(android:statusBarColor inherits the value of android:colorPrimaryDark by default)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/your_custom_color</item>
</style>
```

On API level 21+ you can also use the Window.setStatusBarColor() method from code.

```
// getWindow() is a method of Activity
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Hope this is of any help.